# Issues with C++ template arguments for inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, visual-c++

I have a questions about C++ templates. More specifally, by using template arguments for inheritance.
I am facing strange behaviour in a closed-source 3rd party library. There is a C method

```
factoryReg(const char*, ICallback*)
```

which allows to register a subclass of ICallback and overwrite the (simplified) methods:

```
class ICallback
{
public:
virtual void ENTRY(void* data) = 0;
virtual void EXIT(void* data) = 0;

const char* getName() { return _name; } const
ICallback(const char* name) : _name(name) {}
virtual ~ICallback() {}

private:
const char* _name;
};
```

I have

```
    class BaseCallback : public ICallback
    {
    public:
    BaseCallback(const char* name) : ICallback(name) {}
    virtual void ENTRY(void* data) { 
       std::cout << "in ENTRY base" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void EXIT(void* data) { 
       std::cout << "in EXIT base" << std::endl;
    };

    class  SpecialCallback : public BaseCallback
    {
    public:
    SpecialCallback(const char* name) : BaseCallback(name) {}

    virtual void ENTRY(void* data) { 
    // actually, it's 3rd party code too - assumed to do something like
    ... 
    BaseCallback::ENTRY();
    }

    // no redecl. of EXIT(void* data)
    };

    template <typename Base>
    TemplCallback : public Base
    {
    public:
    TemplCallback(Base& myT) : Base(myT.getName()), _myT(myT)
    virtual void ENTRY(void* data) { 
       std::cout << "in ENTRY templ." << std::endl;
       _myT.ENTRY(); 
    }
    virtual void EXIT(void* data) {
       std::cout << "in EXIT templ." << std::endl;
       _myT.EXIT(); 
    }

    private:
       Base& _myT;
    }
```

Upon registering

```
SpecialCallback spc("validName");
TemplCallback<SpecialCallback> myCallback(spc);
factoryReg(spc.getName(), &myCallback);
...
// output: "in ENTRY base"
//         "in EXIT base"
```

the callback somehow does not work (debug output not being put out // breakpoints do not apply).

If I omit implementation of the EXIT(void* data) method in my template class TemplCallback - everything works fine!

```
// output: "in ENTRY templ."
//         "in EXIT base"
```

Is this expected behaviour? I have been told it might be an issue of the MSVC compiler 13.10.6030 I use. Not sure about that.

BTW: The template idea presented here might not be the best choice for whatever I am trying to do ;)
But I am still interested in the matter itself, regardless about design questions.

Comment: Can you flesh this pidgin C++ out to something that at least has a hope of compiling?  It's hard to be a language lawyer with pseudocode.

Comment: Sorry, I realize the code is a bit thin: fleshed it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that it is safe to assume that SpecialCallback::ENTRY() calls BaseCallback::EXIT() somehow. 
Can't be 100% sure, because it's closed source - but it's quite likely.

So much for "callback" functions...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `factoryReg` doesn't actually invoke the callback, but stores the pointer and invokes the callback when something happens.

If that is the case, then this code:

```
TemplCallback<SpecialCallback> myCallback(spc);
factoryReg(spc.getName(), &myCallback);
```

causes `factoryReg` to store pointer to a temporary, which will go out of scope as soon as your registration function returns. Thus, when the callback is invoked, the object is not alive and you have undefined behaviour.

Your `TemplCallback` class looks funny. I don't think you actually want it to use a different object, but to invoke the inherited versions of `ENTRY` and `EXIT`:

```
template <class Base>
class TemplCallback : public Base
{
public:
    TempCallback(const char* name) : Base(name)
    {}

    virtual ENTRY(void* data) 
    { 
       // do special processing

       Base::ENTRY(data); 
    }

    virtual EXIT(void* data)
    { 
       // do special processing

       Base::EXIT(data); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Valid point about invocation of the base class methods. I thought, to "decorate" a SpecialCallback I would use the "is-a ICallback" and "has-a ICallback" pattern. The TemplCallback, furthermore, is of a different state than the containing SpecialCallback instance.

Comment: About scope: We may assume that the ICallback pointer is always valid (bold assumption, I know - but my test project only remains in a main() function, so no dangling pointers from assignment of local variables).